# Reference request : cohomogeneity one symmetric space

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

In a note, it says that cohomogeneity one symmetric space is one of the following 5 types - $\mathbb{R}^n, S^n, \mathbb{RP}^n, \mathbb{CP}^n, \mathbb{HP}^n, \mathbb{OP}^2$.

Are there some (introductory) books about cohomogeneity of symmetric space and classification of cohomogeneity one symmetric space?

Thank you.